# Why does authenticaton required keeps reappearing despite having all necessary roles?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I know that there are several questions like mine and I've looked into them.

This is my tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="me" password="pass" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

I've set my **CATALINA_HOME** as **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.28**

And my **JAVA_HOME** as **C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4**

And whenever I try to setup tomcat as a server in Netbeans 8.2, I keep getting this pop-up that says "Authentication required XDB" and I write my username and password as it is on the tomcat-users.xml and it only pops back up indefinitely and never yields any result.

Comment: Did you try run Netbeans with Administrator privilege? I mean run as Administrator?

Comment: I just tried and no difference, same results and still getting that authentication pop-up every time I click Ok.